# Are there dangers of using static fields in model class

Tags: java, static

I would like to know if there are cons or pros of using `static` fields or attributes in a **model** class.

For instance I have a model class called Book

```
public class Book{

private int id;
private static int id; //this one
private Category category;

//setters and getters

}
```

I understand that static variable values remain active while programming is running and remain unchanged if not set to a new value using setters.

What are the best practices and when should I use `static` fields in a **Model** class?

Comment: *I understand that static variable values remain active while programming is running and remain unchanged if not set to a new value using setters.*  This is not only for static variables, that's what a regular variable/field does. The particularity about static variables is that they are **shared** across all object of the given class. So all your `Book` instances will have the exact same id. You change it once, it gets changed in all your `Book` instances. The question is: is this what you need? Is a non-unique id useful?

Comment: I'm not sure setters with static variables really make sense

Comment: Use `static` if its value is common to all `Book` instances. The main (only?) dangers are if it is mutable: any instance of `Book` can change its value, is that desirable? And if you do want the field to change, and the code is used by multiple threads, you need to make sure that appropriate steps are taken to ensure synchronization of the updates (which is true of non-static fields too; but it's way worse for static fields).

Comment: @AndyTurner I've used static variables for username. Is that something considered to be a common practice? Thanks.

Comment: If the username is something that only has (and will only ever have) 1 value throughout the system... you could. I'd avoid it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want every instance of a `Book` to have the same `id` then make it `static`.

If that's absurd (and I think it is), then use a non-`static` field.

Comment: Nit: instances of `Book` don't "have" an `id` if it's a static field. Static fields belong to the class, not to its instances.